# Jquery Calling Variable Outside of Function

Tags: jquery, function, variables, alert

I have a function that defines a variable and if i call that veriable inside the function it works fine.  When i try to use alert outside the function it does not work.  What am doing wrong and/or what do i need to do in order to call/alert the function outside of the function.  Thank you.

```
$(function() {
    $("#MyForm").submit(function(){
        $(':input.File').each(function() {  
            $(this).upload(
                'filephp.php', 
                function(success){
                    var fmsg = success;
                    if(fmsg == "E") {var T = 'left';}

                    }, 
                $('#prog')
            )
            alert(T);

        }); 
        return false            
    })

})
```

As you can see im trying to set a variable "T" and then alert it outside of the function.I need to use the variable outside of the function to do more form processing.  Thanks.

Comment: I don't think it is possible because the upload function looks like a asynchronous one

Answer (score 2):

Variable T is out of scope. First define it outside the upload call and then call alert in callback function when upload is completed.

**EDIT**

```
   var T = '';
   ...
   $(this).upload(
      'filephp.php', 
      function(success){
         var fmsg = success;
         if(fmsg == "E") {
             T = 'left';
         }
      }, 
       $('#prog')
    );
    alert(T);
    ...
```

Only problem with this example is that the alert value is ''  not 'left' because callback function is called when upload is completed and that is after alert. So you must call that in sucess callback to get right value.

Comment: I am very new, is there a way you can provide sample code?  Not familiar with callback function.  Thank you

Comment: Put var T outside, like in example. Take care to not override the value, because you have each loop for all files that are uploading.

Comment: If you declare your variable within the function  as you previously have, the scope of that variable is only within that function; you cannot obtain its value outside of the function. However, as shown here, if you declare the variable outside of the function, you can assign it a value within the function which will then be accessible outside of the function.

Comment: The 'success' that is brought back when i run the php file in the background is what sets the var t so how do i set it if i don't run it inside the function?  In short, my file.php not only process the upload but it also checks to see if the file already exists.  If it exist  then i need to stop the form from submitting.  So this is why i need the var set inside the success call.

Comment: What happens if first file already exist on server. You want to stop uploading other files? How you check that the files are the same, by name? If its by name, you can create simple ajax call with all names to check if there is one of them already on server.

Comment: Or maybe its because i am trying to set a variable with the success data object and not a string???  My php page just echo's "E" but im not sure it that is what is actually returned to the jquery script.

Comment: Log success in FF FireBug like this: `console.log(success);` I then see what the value.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have to set "T" as a variable before your function then redefine it in your function with something like T = "lol hai";.

*Edit - So there was a few things wrong with it:
http://jsfiddle.net/vAx6L/2/

Just like you did with the variable "T" you need to set the variable for "fmsg" blank outside of the function too.

In Jquery you can create functions by setting it as a variable see this link:
http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/functions/

There were a few extra un-necessary characters check the console for errors regarding this, the fiddle shows a cut down version of your example as obviously don't have your upload library/plugin.

```
var T;
var fmsg;
var newFunction = function(){
    fmsg = "E";
    if(fmsg == "E"){
        T = 'left';
    }
    alert(T);
}; // no need for a closing ")" here
newFunction(); // This actually calls the function, should be in your document ready/ document load
```

Comment: This returns a blank value.

Comment: Quick thought, does this run the alert before the ajax in complete.If so it would bring back blank value.  I know the  is running my php file asynchronously so  maybe it's calling the alert before the ajax/var set is complete?? Just a thought, if i am correct, is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Or maybe its because i am trying to set a variable with the success data object and not a string???

Comment: Possible depends what "fmsg" is, does it deffo become "E"?
add this before the if console.log(fmsg); and what comes back?

What are you using to upload?

Comment: When i log it it get: TypeError: a is undefined jquery.min.js:3
"E"...so it logs E but with an error before.  To answer you other question my php file runs the query and then echos "E" if successful.

Comment: check my edited original answer for a fiddle. Think that should help. Not sure about the issue you mentioned, though it doesn't sound like it's completely breaking the page otherwise you wouldn't get "E" at all! I would certainly still investigate it though. Maybe you just need to clear the log?

Comment: @user982853 Can you maybe up vote my answer if it helped, the jsfiddle should help you...